# Visual Studio 2010 windows 7 64bit create OpenCV & OpenGL project at the same time

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, windows-7, opencv

I can't get OpenCV to work with OpenGL at the same time at one project on Windows 7 64bit. I have it running ok seperately, but at the same time it just doesn't work.

I follow these steps:

Project -> Properties:

**Configuration Manager**, turn the project to x64 for the OpenCV to work.

**C++ -> General**, under Additional Dependencies include the OpenCV folders:

> normally C:\Program Files\OpenCV2.3\build\include;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

**Linker -> Input**, under Additional Dependencies add OpenCV and OpenGL folders:

> normally "C:\Program Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_core230d.lib";"C:\ProgramFiles\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui230d.lib";"C:\Program
>   Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_video230d.lib";"C:\Program
>   Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_ml230d.lib";"C:\Program
>   Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_legacy230d.lib";"C:\Program
>   Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc230d.lib";"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\lib\freeglut.lib";%(AdditionalDependencies)

But it doesn't work cause VS can't find the freeglut(openGL) files.

Comment: and what are the files that it cant find?

Comment: I would guess that it's missing header files for freeglut. In that case you need to add the directory those are in as a include directory (or move those to VS10's existing directory, since the lib is there).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies!

it shows messages like this: Error 12 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___glutCreateWindowWithExit referenced in function glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK

Answer (score 0):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_MEAN
#pragma comment(linker,"/subsystem:windows")
#pragma comment(lib,"glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")
```

add these lines before including of headers